# Posting JSON to web service (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, json, web-services, http-headers

I am trying to post some JSON to a webservice as below but I keep getting a (400) Bad Request response, I can't seem to figure out why.

**Documentation**

> Send SMS
>
> POST /customers/{customerId}/sms
>
> To send a new SMS, simply POST a representation of a new smsmessage to
>   the list resource. If successful, a representation of the newly
>   created smsmessage will be returned in the body of the response.

POST https://pbx.sipcentric.com/api/v1/customers/25/sms

```
{
  "type": "smsmessage",
  "to": "07902000000",
  "from": "01212854400",
  "body": "Hey, this API is awesome!"
}
```

**My Code**

```
  var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://pbx.sipcentric.com/api/v1/customers/3682/sms");
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    //Encode Password & user
    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
    //attach authentication details to header
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {

        streamWriter.Write(smsJson);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

**And my JSON**

```
{"smsmessage":{"type":"smsmessage","to":"07984389886","from":"07984389886","body":"THIS IS A TEXT MESSAGE"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json should be in the following form:

```
{"type":"smsmessage","to":"07984389886","from":"07984389886","body":"THIS IS A TEXT MESSAGE"}
```

without the outer "smsmessage" encapsulation.

API reference [here](https://developer.sipcentric.com/api/v1/#send-sms).

Comment: I'm now getting a 403 Forbidden error, any idea what that could be?

Comment: @HackoriDotCom You are not authorized to perform that action. Make sure you properly encode the authentication information.

Comment: Bad information gives me 401 unauthorized I think it's something else

Comment: @HackoriDotCom Perhaps your account hasn't got access to this particular API, or your account hasn't got enough credits, or something similar. I am not familiar with this provider. One thing's certain: the user you are logging in with is not allowed to use that API call, whatever the reason.

Comment: @HackoriDotCom I suggest you also read the body of the 403 Forbidden response. It might contain additional info related to the reason why your request was denied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90167/discussion-between-mihai-caracostea-and-hackoridotcom).

Comment: I've got it! I was sending the sms from a disallowed number. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!